# Relation between number of points on elliptic curve and it being cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

This is mainly a question about requirements to determine if an elliptic curve is cyclic. But what I truly don't understand is how do I use knowledge of how many points modulo n the curve has to determine if it is or is not cyclic? I got completly lost when it comes to group theory and don't understand how the number of points affect it.

Comment: What do you mean ? For $\Delta = 27b^2+4a^3 \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$ then $E(\mathbf{F}_p) =\{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{F}_p^2, y^2 \equiv x^3 + ax+b\bmod p\}\cup \{O\}$ is a finite group, and $E(\mathbb{Q}) =\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2, y^2 \equiv x^3 + ax+b\}\cup \{O\}$ is much more complicated.

Comment: The first case, it should be finite group modulo p, yeah. And i wanna find out how can we figure out if it is or is not cyclic from the amount of points it has. So far the only property i know is that it should have even number of points since it has the inverses (i'm guessing this assumption is wrong).

Comment: If $\# E(\mathbf{F}_p) = p+1-a_p$ is square-free then the group is automatically cyclic. Otherwise you need some structure theorems about  elliptic curves over finite fields. Anyway in cryptography you work in the cyclic group generated by a point $P \in E(\mathbf{F}_p) $ so you don't care if the whole group is cyclic or not.

Comment: Okey what about this. Based on this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368707/how-do-you-determine-if-an-elliptic-curve-over-a-finite-field-is-cyclic#368738 . If the amount of points is square of some number it would be isomorphic thus if it is 2 different numbers it would be cyclic. Is that right?

Comment: In the linked question $p+1-a_p = 3^2$ and $3$ is prime thus it can only be $C_9$ (cyclic) or $C_3 \times C_3$ (non-cyclic)

Comment: So is my assumption about factoring correct as well?

Comment: Assumption about what ? If $G$ is abelian and $|G| = \prod_{j=1}^l p_j^{e_j}$ then the number of possible group structures is $\prod_{j=1}^l \mathcal{P}(e_j)$, only one of them is cyclic, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the partition function : $3 = 2+1=1+1+1$ so $\mathcal{P}(3) = 3$

Comment: The assumption that if the number of points is not factorizable into squares it is cyclic. And i don't really understand what you said about the group in the last comment. Could you explain?

Comment: $n$ squarefree means $n = \prod_{j=1}^l p_j$ with the $p_j$ distinct primes, ie. $m^2 | n \implies m= 1$. To make my last comment clear you need to see how $3 = 2+1=1+1+1$ gives $3$ isomorphism classes of abelian groups of order $p^3$

Comment: What does $a_p$ represent?

Comment: It is just the common name for $p+1-\# E(F_p) $ which is [bounded by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) $2\sqrt{p}$ and the algorithms to compute $\# E(F_p) $ do really compute $a_p$

Comment: But isn't $p+1-2\sqrt{p}= 5[,36..]$ for 11?

Comment: In your linked post, $p= 11, \#E(F_p) = p+1-a_p = 9, a_p = 3 $ so $|a_p| \le 2 \sqrt{p}$

Comment: But how did you get $a_p = 3$? Isn't $ #E(F_{p}) $ the number of points? I'm getting uterly and totaly confused here but i guess you noticed, sorry for that.

Comment: I meant $-3= 9-12$. If I mentioned it, it is because it is in every book on elliptic curves

Comment: To be honest i haven't even gotten the time to properly study them as we got them as a one lecture thing and i gotta figure out their properties. I'll ask quite stupid question but,... how do you calculate order of element? (a name for algorithm or link is enough)

Comment: Not sure, make some research, and play with [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) `p:=11; F := GF(p); E := EllipticCurve([F | 1, 0]); E; #E; P := Points(E); P; P[1]+P[3];`